# Android options menu is transparent

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

I have been struggling with this problem for a while. I have no action bar but I do have a options menu. The options menu is transparent I can't get it to be not transparent. This problem arises because of the theme: **`Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`** or any like `Theme.AppCompact.Light.` I have tried many things like setting `android:panelFullBackground` or similar but they do not work or them make all my screen dark for split-seconds when options menu is out.

I did find a somewhat useful solution which is I extended `ActionBarActivity` and set the Theme to **`Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`** but when you press the options menu button you hear the button pressing sound twice.

Please help me. I would like a xml fix or a different (similar though to what I'm using) theme(that works with tabs too).

Comment: Can we see your xml file? Also, what version of Android are you testing on?

Comment: did you find a normal solution to make this popup/window if menu transparent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick fix would be to change `android:panelBackground`. It is set to transparent by default by `Theme.AppCompat`

Comment: what exactly did you try?

Comment: @frgnvola he and I wanted to make popup menu window transparent, but `android:panelBackground` does nothing

Answer (score 7):

Change itemBackground parameter in styles.xml

```
<item name="android:itemBackground">@color/white</item>
```

Comment: it's separate background for each item, what if I have background with borders? I will get border around each item..

Comment: also it would not make menu transparent because you have another background below all items - popup/window background

Answer (score 0):

Change the theme to android:Theme.NoTitleBar. It looks similar enough to Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar